# Show/Hide Submenu in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I know there's tons of pages dedicated to this on SO but my piece of code just doesn't seem to work. I keep getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  I've made use of jquery to show/hide my wordpress submenu when a user hover over the parent. (See code below)

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('.menu .nav li > .sub-menu').parent().hover(function() {
 var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
 if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
 $(submenu).slideDown(200);
} else {
$(submenu).slideUp(200);
 }
});
```

HTML

```
    <div id="masthead" class="menu navbar navbar" role="banner">
    <div class="logo-navbar container-logo">
        <div class="container-fullwidth">
            <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="menu-left-container"><ul id="menu-left" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-184" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-239" class="menu-item">        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-238" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-237" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-240" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-Item 3</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="logo.png">
        </a>
      <div class="menu-right-container"><ul id="menu-right" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 3 Illustrations</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-189" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
          </div>
```

I guess im not referencing the right function. Hope somebody helps me out!

Cheers!

Comment: @S .ko can you provide live demo like codepen or other please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure:

1.- You have included jQuery on the header/footer of your page.
2.- If you are using native `jQuery` from WordPress is defined as `jQuery` not as `$`.
3.- You should wrap your code inside of a `$(document).ready` function.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.menu .nav li > .sub-menu').parent().hover(function() {
            var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
            if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
                $(submenu).slideDown(200);
            } else {
                $(submenu).slideUp(200);
            }
        });
    });
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Reasons:

1.- You can test this on the chrome console by typing `$` or `jQuery` in the console, and you should have and output like:

```
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
```

2.- If you are using the jQuery included by WordPress you need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` as mentioned before to avoid conflicts with other libs.

3.- Since otherwise the code is executed as soon as the document is `ready` if not your code can be executed before the `DOM` elements are on the document.

Comment: This was excellent advice. Worked like a charm. Seems i forgot the  "$(document).ready(function()". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing jQuery properly? If not add this to the header.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

If that isn't the issue you can also try to see if adding $ = jQuery to the top of your script does the trick.